# Flex: Setting Minimum and Maximum Dates on a dateHSlider

Tags: apache-flex, date

I need some help using this [dateHSlider](http://www.cftips.net/downloads/dateHSliderExample/srcview/).

I need to change the starting and ending dates, so that the earliest date that can be chosen is January 1, 2011 and the latest date that can be chosen is April 30, 2011. Also, the user should only be able to select 30 days at a time.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So essentially, you're asking us to do the work for you without even trying...

Answer (score 0):

Set the default date range in **dateHSliderExample.mxml** file's `creationComplete` method **`init()`**